# Will LangChain-AgentExecutor automatically provide the "intermediate_steps"?

Tags: agent, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

When I read LangChain Doc. I got a question. Here is the link: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/#define-the-agent

There is a variable `agent_scratchpad`  in the prompt template which should be a sequence of messages that contains the previous agent tool invocations and the corresponding tool outputs. I want to know where can I get the input variable `x["intermediate_steps"]`?

```py
from langchain.agents.format_scratchpad import format_to_openai_function_messages
from langchain.agents.output_parsers import OpenAIFunctionsAgentOutputParser

agent = (
    {
        "input": lambda x: x["input"],
        "agent_scratchpad": lambda x: format_to_openai_function_messages(
            x["intermediate_steps"]
        ),
    }
    | prompt
    | llm_with_tools
    | OpenAIFunctionsAgentOutputParser()
)

.....

agent_executor = AgentExecutor(
        agent=agent, 
        tools=tools, 
        verbose=True)
```

However, in this tutorial , The `return_intermediate_steps` of AgentExecutor is set to default(False). And it only provide `input` and `chat_history` like this.

```py
agent_executor.invoke({"input": input1, "chat_history": chat_history})
agent_executor.invoke({"input": "is that a real word?", "chat_history": chat_history})
```

I want to know where is `intermediate_steps` from? Is it automatically generated by AgentExecutor?